# readShapeSpatial fails with simplified mapshaper.org shape

Tags: r, mapping, mapshaper

So I'm mapping out the postal regions of my country and it's an enormous, 5.4million row dataframe.  I don't need every single little twist and turn of the boundries, so I was super excited to discover [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org).  Seemed easy enough, I just threw my .shp file into it, and it spit back a file 10% of the size!  Excellent!

Nope..  now it doesn't play with readShapeSpatial...  Hopefully I won't need to provide the shapefile (i can track it down if that parts really necessary)

Original code, works:

```
canada.shp <- readShapeSpatial("canada", verbose=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
```

New map, doesn't:

```
canada.shp <- readShapeSpatial("simplecanada", verbose=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
Shapefile type: Polygon, (5), # of Shapes: 1621
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",  : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In .Map2PolyDF(Map, IDs = IDvar, proj4string = proj4string, force_ring = force_ring,  :
  Null objects with the following indices deleted: 895
```

traceback() reveals:

```
4: stop("attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions")
    3: `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
   "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
   "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
   "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
   "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", (ETC!!!!)
2: .Map2PolyDF(Map, IDs = IDvar, proj4string = proj4string, force_ring = force_ring, 
       delete_null_obj = delete_null_obj, retrieve_ABS_null = retrieve_ABS_null)
1: readShapePoly("simplecanada", 
       verbose = TRUE, delete_null_obj = TRUE)
```

Comment: How about reducing the size of the shapefile using R? Here is a [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71094/reduce-the-resolution-of-a-shapefile-in-r-or-qgis-if-necessary) for you.

Comment: I looked into that, and I've been running dp() for the past hour now.. takes forever!  Would love to be able to just use the shape data from mapshaper.org--not sure why it doesn't load

Comment: I am not a gis person, so I have no clue. At least, the new file has something R does not like. It is worth posting on gis.exchange. You probably get more attention.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115186/using-r-readshapespatial-fails-with-simplified-mapshaper-org-shape)